# read file in disk encrypt with out mount it

Tags: objective-c, macos

I create disk encrypt in mac OS X ML 10.8 (use Disk utiliti or use command hdiutil ). I want read file in that disk, but I can't mount it. Because when I mount it, another app can read it before I unmount. Please help me.(hdiutil command here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would have to read and decrypt the dmg file yourself and then interpret the HFS file system inside the disk image to get at your file. It's not easy but certainly possible. Take a look at the [HFSExplorer](http://catacombae.org.preview.binero.se/hfsx.html) source code.

But I wouldn't put too much energy into this. Either use a different file format that is easier to read to store your encrypted data, or go with pajps solution. And remember, no matter what you do, once you decrypt your file the user will be able to get to the decrypted data. You can make this harder, but you can't prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only reasonable way would be to mount the disk image. To do it securely, you can use the `-mountrandom` and `-nobrowse` options to `hdiutil attach`. This will mount the disk image in a randomized path name, and prevent it from being visible in the UI.

```
hdiutil attach -mountrandom /tmp -nobrowse /tmp/secret_image.dmg
```

Assuming the disk image has one and exactly one HFS partition, you can parse the randomized mount path like this:

```
hdiutil attach -mountrandom /tmp -nobrowse /tmp/secret.dmg | awk '$2 = /Apple_HFS/ { print $3 }'
```

Or you can use the -plist option to get the output in plist XML format that can be parsed using XML tools or converted to json using `plutil -convert json`.

Of course, an attacker that has root access can still monitor for new mounts and intercept your disk image before you have the chance to unmount it, but if your attacker has root than pretty much all bets are off.

Comment: I still see disk .in Mac os X , in Finder ,go ->Computer ,disk still visible by show hidden file in finder.when mount disk,it always visible in Finder (go->computer) by show hidden file.thanks.